# "Has been" can this be considered Present tense

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

My daughter wrote

> Sarah has been reading books about gardening.

I am a little confused as to how to categorize this. Can it be considered Present tense? Is this sentence acceptable?

Comment: "Has been reading" is the _present perfect continuous_ tense of the verb _to read._ Your daughter writes well in English.  Can you tell us what led you to think otherwise, or why you thought the verb might be in the present tense? (To learn how to conjugate the irregular verb _to read_ in English, follow [**this link.**](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/read))

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!  She got this sentence marked wrong on a test where had to present.  The main sentence was "Sarah reads books about gardening. She needed to write it in present.

Comment: If we had more context, such as the complete question from the exam, we could provide more help. Can you use the [edit] link under the question to add this context? The sentence is perfectly grammatical, but may not be the correct answer. For instance, if the question was "What is Sarah doing right now?" and it included a picture of Sarah reading a book, the answer would be incorrect. (Note also that teachers are not infallible! Is your daughter's teacher a native English speaker?)

Comment: If the test required your daughter to write in the _simple present,_ that would be: _Sarah reads books about gardening._ But note that the question may have been unclear, or written by a non-native English speaker. The sentence she wrote _is_ in one of the present tenses, but not in the _simple present._

Comment: It seems kind of unfair to state the question sentence in the simple present tense and ask to convert to present tense. I call void the question on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's acceptable and part of present tenses grammatically.

There're **four** present tense forms:

**Present simple/simple present:** *Sarah reads books about gardening.*

**Present continuous:** *Sarah is reading books about gardening.*

**Present perfect:** *Sarah has read books about gardening.*

**Present perfect continuous:** *Sarah has been reading books about gardening.*

Please bear in mind that the action (reading the books) in your example, has been done from a point in the past until now.